# R RMySQL fetch big ints as strings

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I want to use RMySQL to work with SQL table.This table has `bigint(20) unsigned` type column containing hash sum (64 bit unsigned type). When fetching it from table, hash gets converted to floating point number, rendering it useless. Is there a way to fetch such columns as strings?

This is the code I use to fetch data:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                 host="192.168.1.2",
                 port = 3306,
                 user="root",
                 password="password")
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from data.message")
data <- dbFetch(res, 1)
dbClearResult(res)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: Try to `cast` it as `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was found to be, as pointed by @akrun, to cast `int` to `varchar` in SQL query itself.

`dbSendQuery` was modified like so:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "select time, convert(state, char(20)), client, message from data.message")
```